# A jar contains 8 red balls and 2 blue balls. Every minute, a ball is randomly removed. The probability that there exists a time during this process…

Tags: probability, contest-math

A jar contains 8 red balls and 2 blue balls. Every minute, a ball is randomly removed. The probability
that there exists a time during this process where there are more blue balls than red balls in the jar can
be expressed as a
b
for relatively prime integers a and b. Compute 100a + b.

I got the probability  =$\frac{11}{90}$

Can someone confirm?

Comment: This is an instance of the [ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem)

Comment: What is the contest?

Comment: HMMT Feb 2022 contest

Comment: This is what remains in the jar. I thought it is quite straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Case i) All the red balls are removed from the jar with 2 blue balls in it

Case ii) All the red + 1 blue ball are removed from the jar with 1 blue ball in it

Case i) Prob: $\frac{8}{10}.\frac{7}{9}\cdots\frac{2}{4}.\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{45}$

Case II) prob: $\frac{{8\choose 8}.{2\choose 1}}{{10\choose9}}=\frac{2}{10}$

Sum of these $= \frac{2}{9}$

Using ballot theorem: the probability that there are more red balls than blue $= \frac{8+1-2}{8+1}$

Thus the probability that there are more blue balls than red all the time = $1-\frac{7}{9} = \frac{2}{9}$

Comment: Hard to follow.  To do the count directly (without quoting the ballot theorem): Look at the extraction list backwards.  The only bad cases are "take $B$" first and take $RBB$ in that order.  Easy to compute both.

Comment: Look at my comment, it more Blue balls than red remaining in the jar I thought

Comment: Yes, exactly.  In order for there to be more $B$ than $R$ left, the backwards list must start with a $B$ or it must start $RBB$.

Comment: Or just use the ballot theorem (again applied to the backwards list). Remember, we must consider allow ties, which of course is a standard variant.

Comment: There are only $45$ ways to pull the balls, so $11/90$ is impossible.

Comment: @lulu, when you list backwards, the answer seems to be correct.  Thanks

Comment: No problem.  I suggest editing your post to include the correct computation.

Comment: Post edit:  this is now correct, though I still think it is a lot easier to work backwards.  The probability of starting (the backwards list) with $B$ is $\frac 15$.  The probability of starting it with $RBB$ is $\frac 1{45}$.  And $\frac 15+\frac 1{45}=\frac 29$.

Comment: @lulu, you must be widely read to immediately quote ballot theorem.  Thanks for confirming the result

Comment: It comes up as the first application of the Reflection Principle (discussed in the article I linked to).  That's an extremely useful computational tool for analyzing random walks.

Comment: I have also attempted one other Combinaotircs question that i posted, wondering if you could let me knwo the answer

Comment: I was concerned because there is overlap between case i and case ii, so I decided to literally map out the different cases - letting $(b,r)$ denote $b$ blues and $r$ red balls left.  If you look at the cases when $b+r=3$, they are $(2,1)$, $(1,2)$ and $(0,3)$ with prob: 6/90, 42/90 and 42/90 resp.  We count the first one (that's 6/90).  The only other case that needs to be counted is from $(1,2)$ if you pick 2 more reds consecutively.   That is (42/90)(2/3)(1/2)=14/90.   Total=2/9.  Under $(2,1)$ there is a $(1,0)$ (the overlap) but only 1 which exactly offsets the 1 counted under $(1,2)$.